# Trying to run a markdown code on my notebook and having some issues what do i do?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, data-science, markdown, data-analysis, data-science-experience

i am trying to use markdown code to import an img on my jupyter notebook when i press shift enter instead of displaying the img it[this is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3y4S.png)  will shift to a new cell and u will see the code you input not see the image.

This are  the code i have tried

Answer (score 0):

Well, First: Ensure that you've executed the Markdown cell containing the image display code (Shift + Enter) before any other cells that reference or use the image.

and Secondly: Verify that the cell containing the Markdown code is set to render output as Markdown and not as raw text or code.